# Socket - asynchronous image loading in ListView

Tags: android, image, sockets, listview, asynchronous

Help please solve my problem. I use the code for asynchronous image downloading from this site http://www.technotalkative.com/android-asynchronous-image-loading-in-listview/. With HTTP it works as it should, but if I change the piece when with

```
URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
```

On this one

```
Socket socket1 = new Socket();
socket1.connect(new InetSocketAddress(mSettings.getString(APP_PREFERENCES_IPSERVER, ""), 30100), 5000);
ObjectOutputStream outp1 = new ObjectOutputStream(socket1.getOutputStream());
ObjectInputStream inp1 = new ObjectInputStream(socket1.getInputStream());
outp1.writeObject("ASprUserEdir,-,fileget,-," + url);
outp1.flush();
String messageReceived = (String) inp1.readObject();
int file_size = Integer.valueOf(messageReceived.split(",-,")[1]);
InputStream is=socket1.getInputStream();
```

Then if the connection is slow, if you scroll the Sheet, the picture is not displayed in its place. How can this be fixed? Maybe need a different code for this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you try to download an image you need to consider few problem. Example caching, out of memory due to the image size and more and more.

The simlest way is using library such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). They download the image asynchronous, caching the image, memory caching to prevent out of memory etc. It is easy to learn and use.

Comment: The libraries you offer work with http and I need a socket

Answer (score 0):

Use Library Picasso or Glide 
and then used following code

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Please go through the following link for more detail on [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: The libraries you offer work with http and I need a socket

Comment: you can download image through socket and give it to Picasso for draw in image view.